# change the color of each interior (histogram) chart vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts

I have a chart (access) type [column] with several interior (histograms) I want to give each a interior a different color via code

This code allows you to change the color of all the interior with the same color
Obj.seriescollection(1).Interior.color = RGB(150, 150, 150)

but I want to change each interior with a different color

i use class MSGraph.Chart.8
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution :

```
With ChartObject        
        For i = 1 To .SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
            .SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = ClientColor(i)
        Next i        
 End With
```

ClientColor is a table that contains lists the colors